# NodeJs Upload file Error: Request Aborted

Tags: node.js, cordova, file-upload, formidable

I'm trying to upload files (pictures) from an application that I'm developing with Cordova (Phonegap), but I always obtain an `Error: Request Aborted`. At the beginning I was using the `fs.readFile()` that was the first thing that I read, but now I use `Fomidable` but the error is the same:

**Error**

```
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (../XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/nodeyag/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:131:17)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at abortIncoming (http.js:1912:11)
    at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (http.js:1924:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at TCP.close (net.js:466:12)
```

**/picUpload**

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(files);
});

form.on('end',function(fields,files) {
    // temporary location of the uploaded file
    var tempPath = this.openedFiles[0].path;
    // filename of the uploaded file
    var fileName = this.openedFiles[0].name,
    newPath = config.uploadPicsDir + '/docs/';

    var file = { tempPath: tempPath, fileName: fileName };
        console.log(file);

        fs.copy(tempPath, newPath + 'picture.jpg' , function(err) {
            if(err) return next(err);

            console.log("file success!");

            res.send('Ok');
       });//end of copy()
});
```

For copy the file, I'm using the module fs-extra.
What can I do??

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am also getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of express are you using ?

form multipart middleware is removed in express 4

If that's the case try using this: https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy